# How to pass a string in a string

Tags: javascript, string, onclick

I generate a table row with a link like below:

```
"<td>"+table.rows[i].c[0].v+"<a href='#' onclick='loadForm("+table.rows[i].c[2].v+")'>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Link</a></td>" +
```

`table.rows[i].c[2].v = 'my stuff'`.

However, in inspect it generated like

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadForm(my stuff)">&nbsp;&nbsp;My Link</a>
```

Which doesn't work since 'my stuff' doesn't have quotes around it to make it a string. How do I make my stuff a string in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: The quotation marks are not part of the string value, they are delimiters for the parser to know whether the string value starts and where it ends.

Comment: Do you have to do this as strings? Things are much easier if you create elements as objects, then use `element.addEventListener()` to add the click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Put quotes in your string around the argument, escaped with a backslash `\`:

```
"<td>"+table.rows[i].c[0].v+"<a href='#' onclick='loadForm(\""+table.rows[i].c[2].v+"\")'>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Link</a></td>" +
```

Long answer: Don't build HTML elements with strings, it's inefficient and poorly maintainable. Instead, use the standard DOM functions:

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '#';
a.onclick = function() { loadForm(table.rows[i].c[2].v); }
a.textContent = '  My Link';
td.appendChild(a);
```

...and then you can use `appendChild()` to append your `td` to the row where it belongs. I know it's longer and looks more of a hassle, but it's *much* easier to debug and maintain. There are also libraries like jQuery to help make it quicker and easier. I'd definitely suggest investing the time and effort to read up on it. Google "HTML DOM" and look around for tutorials, MDN usually has pretty good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would work here:

```
`<td> ${table.rows[i].c[0].v}<a href='#' onclick='loadForm("${table.rows[i].c[2].v}")'>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Link</a></td>`
```